# In Haskell, how to do a case statement on Dynamic TypeRef

Tags: haskell, dynamic, types, pattern-matching, case-statement

I tried the following:

```
intType =  typeOf (5::Int)
stringType = typeOf "s"

dynFunc :: Dynamic -> IO ()
dynFunc d =
  case dynTypeRep d of
    stringType -> polyFunc ((fromDyn d "") :: String)
    intType -> polyFunc ((fromDyn d 0) :: Int)
    _      -> error "Could not coerce dynamic value"
```

But it warns of overlapping pattern matches and doesn't work right. It always goes to first pattern instead of the correct one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The left hand sides of the `->` in a `case` expression are [*patterns*, not expressions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching). The pattern `stringType` will match *anything* and bind the local name `stringType` to it. It will *not* compare for equality.

The compiler is telling you that your patterns `intType` and `_` will never be reached; since the `stringType` pattern comes first and matches anything, its right hand side will always be chosen.

As Claudiu suggested, you'll want to use guards instead. Something like this should do the trick:

```
dynFunc d | rep == stringType = ...
          | rep == intType    = ...
          | otherwise         = error ...
          where rep = dynTypeRep d
```

If you have many possibilities, you might want to consider making a list and using the [`lookup`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:lookup) function.